# React Native error: Raw " " must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> Component

Tags: react-native

[image]

Hi, I am having this error in react native and cannot figure out what is causing it. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue is whitespace. Using tabs however does not count as whitespace. Try removing the space between the *tag* and the *comment* in lines 32 and 37.

```
<View> {/*green*/}
```

should be either

```
<View>{/*green*/}
```

or

```
<View>
    {/*green*/}
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 19):

I encountered a similar error when checking whether to render a component in the following manner:

```
{somevariable && <Text>abcd</Text>}
```

Whenever `somevariable` was 0, that `somevariable` would be interpreted as something that was supposed to be rendered and thus 0 is an invalid React Element.  To resolve this, I made sure that the first expression always evaluated to a boolean.

```
{!!somevariable && <Text>abcd</Text>}
```

Comment: Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove whitespace between tag. Take a look at each or put show whitespace in webstorm `Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance`

Comment: Worked! Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this error, but in my case I accidentally modified / auto formatted some `.js` files and messed up the JSX. And I cannot easily trace the source of the JSX component I messed up. The way I solved my problem surprisingly is to delete the `node_module` folder and reinstall all the node packages by `npm install` at the root folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved the problem, the answer is need to add a space:

```
 <View style={{width:40, height:40, backgroundColor:"green", margin:5}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:18}}>格子{this.state.size1}</Text>
                </View>
```

not

格子{this.state.size1}

Answer (score 0):

On latest releases, you can try the following,
[getting stack traces](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/15544/commits/aebe9cc00349188475ac86ed3d9a8b68b737fd93)