# React Native Error Raw Text "1997" must be wrapped in an explicit <text> component

Tags: react-native

I have a function that loops through and grabs the year of of a year property in an object. I'm trying to render it in the `title` prop of my list view but I get this error.

`Error: raw text "1997" must be wrapped in an explicit <text> component`

My function

```
renderRow = (year) => { 
    return (
        <ListItem 
            key={year.id} 
            title={year.year} 
            onPress={() => this.props.dispatch(storeUserYear(year))}
            underlayColor='#eceeef'
        />
    ) 
}
```

I saw something similar on stackoverflow but it had to do with whitespace [React Native error: Raw " " must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681173/react-native-error-raw-must-be-wrapped-in-an-explicit-text-component)

How do I get rid of this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `ListItem` a component you are implementing yourself?

Comment: ListItem is a component from React Native Elements https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-elements

Comment: That seems strange, because as Matt says, the problem seems to be inside the component. Are you sure that's the code that is triggering it? Which file/line number are you getting?

Comment: Well the first error I get looking at it now is `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `title` supplied to 'ListItem'` but the documentation pretty clearly states it takes a title prop and there have been no issues w/ the other `ListItem` components https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-elements#lists

Answer (score 0):

The error is in  your `ListItem` component, not here. Make sure the year is wrapped in a `<Text>...</Text>` wherever you're calling `props.title`.