# Images in React native after switch case

Tags: image, react-native, switch-statement, state

I have a list of images that I want to display and I can't do that dynamically. So, I did a massive switch case to know which image to display each time: no in the render of the page, I made `renderImage`: a function that contains a switch case and then in the render of the component itself I use `renderImage` but I get every time Null (the default value that I set). Here is the code I used:

```
class CountryDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        fl =  this.props.flag
    };

    static propTypes = {
        popRoute: React.PropTypes.func,
        navigation: React.PropTypes.shape({
            key: React.PropTypes.string,
        }),
    }

    popRoute() {
        this.props.popRoute(this.props.navigation.key);
    }

    render() {
        console.log('image ' , fl)
        return (
            <Container>
                <Header style={{  backgroundColor: '#C0C0C0' }} hasTabs>

                    <Body>
                    <Text style={{ color: '#FFF', fontSize:17, fontWeight:'bold'}}> {this.props.name} </Text>
                    </Body>
                    <Right>
                        <View> {this.renderImage()} </View>
                    </Right>
                </Header>
            </Container>
        );
    }

renderImage() {
   console.log('image ' , fl)
    switch (fl)
        {
        case 'image1':
            return (
        <Image source={require('path/image1.png')}/>
   );
case 'image2':
        return (
     <Image 
               source={require('path/image2.png')}/>     );
    case 'image3':
        return ( 
<Image 
               source={require('path/image3.png')}/>    );
default:
        return (
        <View >
            <Text>{'Null'}</Text>
        </View>
        );
}}}
```

I keep getting Null, the default value that I set, every time in the screen.

After trying `<View> {this.renderImage()} <View/>` I get this error:

```
RawText "" must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> component.
```

**PS** I have other components to return in my render method like title and footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that is the correct way to use `Image`. Try the following code:

```js
// .. rest of the code
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.renderImage()}
    </View>
  )
}

renderImage() {
  switch (img) {
    case 'image1':
        return (<Image source={require('path/image1.png')}/> );
    // .. rest of the case
    default:
        return (
            <Text>{'Null'}</Text>
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: hey thank you .. i tried it and i got another error .. please see the edit as i will post the new error

Comment: hey, i tried this one two and i keep getting the very same error : row text must be wrapped in ""  .. as the las the picture in the question

Comment: Check that this does not apply to your current code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681173/react-native-error-raw-must-be-wrapped-in-an-explicit-text-component

Comment: yeeeees, it worked ... thank you .. i really didn't think that can be caused by a whitespace

Comment: If we have some action for that button action, where can we write in your code?